# Open Count - MobilePush Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios, sdk

I had noted an issue with the Analytics Open Count on push notification on IOS/Android Devices.

The methods from [docs](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html) [available](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html)%20and%20(https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/analytics.html) are already implemented, but notification opens are not being recorded.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: That's a lot of detail that has NOTHING to do with or any way to effect open analytics.  For Android, are you overriding the SDK's notification handling?  Show me your redacted SDK initialization code and any accompanying NotificationOptions code please.  For iOS, did you implement the service extension and are you calling the SDK's convenience method to track the open?  Show me your service extension please.

Comment: Android NotificationCustomization Doc https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configureforpush.html

Comment: Hello @BillMote

These points you passed are enabled within our APP, and working correctly when we don't run our backend routine, we run the routine below, because for Security reasons we don't pass our ID directly into the Marketing Cloud SDK.

Comment: 1. First Download: When the customer downloads to the Store (Apple Store - Play Store)
2. Marketing Cloud SDK: Marketing Cloud SDK launches and registers a new contact in Marketing Cloud.
3. SalesForce Marketing Cloud: The New contact is created by the SDK with the following parameters: Contact_key, Device_ID, System_token, Platform.

Comment: 4. Internal Service: When the client first accesses the APP, the following information: user_id, device_id, system_token, platform are sent to internal service.
5. Check Device: A validation is performed if the device is authorized or not.
6. Device Storage: Stored in the authorization status database

Comment: 7.When the device is authorized, the **CONTACT_KEY** EXCHANGE that had been generated by the SDK, for the identification key used by our client. Using the APIS below and keeping only the required information (device_id, platform, system_tokem)

Comment: APIS 

POST:/V2/token
POST:/contacts/v1/contacts/search
POST:/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?Type=keys
POST:/contacts/v1/contacts

Comment: Your contact key has _NOTHING_ to do with open tracking.

Comment: i have the same error
[Questions Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393448/how-can-i-send-analytic-event-about-push-open-in-android-sdk)